# Having a run mode and an edit mode

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a question regarding running the same application in different "modes".
Basically, I want the app to be editable if you know what you're doing (e.g. you're an admin of sorts) but not if you're just using it.
I was thinking about making a bool/int value and make it hide show elements based on the mode. But is this the correct way? is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: so far i have tried binding a bool with visibility to stop my popups from hapening and using the same bool in my methods and returning if its true. i'm just afraid that this might not be the best approach as it still checks to se if it should run or not.

Comment: You need to show what code you have tried and where you got stuck

Comment: It's not that i'm stuck :) what i've tried works so far. I just want to know if that is the "correct" way to do it or if there is another way of doing it.

Comment: Worry less about the "how" and more about the "what"; what are you trying to achieve? The admin rights you're alluding to could vary from simply giving someone access to an extra page, for settings for example, right through to the ability to override things all over the place. Once you decide "what" your options, and solution, may become clearer. Happy to make suggestions if you give a little more information.

Comment: okay so basically the application is this:
The "admin" will drag in some symbols from a list and arrange them on a canvas. These symbols will each have some settings which the admin also will set (settings like name, min/max value, color condition if value is x)
The user does not have all these permissions and should only be allowed to read the setting but also be able to click on some of the symbols and change them from "open" to "closed.

Thats basically the program :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to have a single setting in the ViewModel that reflects the logical requirement. If there are only two options, it should be a boolean.

You probably have to think carefully about which controls need to be disabled, hidden or read-only. For example, control with a scroll bar shouldn't be disabled or the user won't be able to scroll. Text boxes could be either (read-only allow the user to select and copy, disabled doesn't). Other controls could be disabled, if there's some way that the user can enable them (e.g. a save button that is only enabled once there are changes to save), or hidden if the user will only ever have a read-only view.

You'll most likely need a few ValueConverters to convert the boolean 'IsAdmin' (or whatever) flag to values that the WPF expects. For example you can bind IsEnabled directly, but IsReadOnly will be a converter to invert it. If you want to hide something, you'll need a converter like this:

```
public class BoolVisiblityInverseConverter: IValueConverter
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(bool))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("BoolVisiblityInverseConverter can only accept a bool");
        }

        var val = (bool)value;
        return val ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to define it in the Resources section of your XAML

```
<converters:BoolVisiblityInverseConverter x:Key="BoolVisiblityInverseConverter" />
```

and bind it to the Visibility property

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding IsAdmin, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisiblityInverseConverter}}" />
```

The goal with this method is that the interface between the View and ViewModel is as simple as possible. The VM can decide what mode to use, and the View displays every control in a suitable state.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can easy do it with Visibility Converter. Place editable control and readonly control in same place.

Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <myapp:BoolToVisible x:Key="bool2visible"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode}">Mode on</CheckBox>

            <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" Visibility="{Binding Mode, Converter={StaticResource bool2visible}, ConverterParameter=1}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Number}" Visibility="{Binding Mode, Converter={StaticResource bool2visible}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Bool to visibility converter

```
public class BoolToVisible:IValueConverter
{

public BoolToVisible()
{

}

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var val=(bool)value;
    if (parameter?.ToString() == "1")
    {
        val=!val;
    }
    if (val)
    {
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }else
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

}

Comment: yes, and any guest user can inpect such app in Snoop, make necesssary elements visible and edit whatever as admin

Comment: @ASh - good point, OP will also need to check permissions before committing any changes.